# Use external api having oauth2 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docusignapi

I need to call an external API from my spring boot project. The external API is using OAuth 2 security authentication using authorization_code. I have the client id and secret key, any suggestion would be great.

Tried using SDK provided by DocuSign but while getting access token facing issue as 400 with message consent required.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is do download a "quickstart" from DocuSign and pick Java for your language. This does a lot more than just give you Java code, it also configures everything you need for you to be able to make API calls.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

The specific Java code that does Auth Code Grant authentication can be found here:

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/core/controller/GlobalControllerAdvice.java

```
OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
OAuth2User oauthUser = oauth.getPrincipal();
OAuth2AuthorizedClient oauthClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
        oauth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
        oauthUser.getName()
);

if (oauth.isAuthenticated()) {
    user.setName(oauthUser.getAttribute("name"));
    
    if (oauthClient != null){
        user.setAccessToken(oauthClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
    } else {
        user.setAccessToken(((OAuth.OAuthToken) oauthUser.getAttribute("access_token")).getAccessToken());
    }

    if (account.isEmpty()) {
        account = Optional.ofNullable(getDefaultAccountInfo(getOAuthAccounts(oauthUser)));
    }

    OAuth.Account oauthAccount = account.orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(ERROR_ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND));
    session.setAccountId(oauthAccount.getAccountId());
    session.setAccountName(oauthAccount.getAccountName());
    // TODO set this more efficiently with more APIs as they're added in
    String basePath = this.getBaseUrl(apiIndex, oauthAccount) + apiIndex.getBaseUrlSuffix();
    session.setBasePath(basePath);
}
```